# Java class not detecting close brace

Tags: java

I have 118 lines of code for a small to-do list app, just making it for fun. The class will not detect the close brace if I put it anywhere after 51.

[Here is the code](https://github.com/NTS716/TooDoo/blob/master/TooDoo.java)

Comment: Can you include the code?

Comment: After a quick glance it looks like your missing the closing bracket for the class itself, all the way at the bottom.

Comment: I left the close bracket out on purpose, I've figured out it is some problem with vim or tmux. I still have no idea why it's happening

Comment: `new` is **not** a valid identifier.

Comment: Don't write your code in a text editor.  Otherwise stuff like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void view()
{
    System.out.print("Enter the name of the task: ");
    String taskToView = scanner.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        if (taskToView.equals(tasks.get(i).name)){ // add one here
            System.out.println(tasks.get(i).name);
        }
    }
} // add one here
```

As pointed out by the comments there is nothing wrong here. I missed the opening brace in that if statement. To add those two in the above method is optional, since you use it like that in all the other methods.

You only need to add one at the end to close the class.

```
public class TooDoo {

    // all the other methods

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Welcome Message
        System.out.println("TooDoo 1.0.0");
        getInp();
    }
} // add one here to close the class
```

Also:

```
String inp_description = scanner.nextLine
```

should be:

```
String inp_description = scanner.nextLine();
```

and you can't use `new` as a name for a method since `new` is a keyword and that gives compiler issues.

at line 108 `view()` is missing the semi-colon `view();`

There are some other issues Netbeans warns about, for example:

```
tasks.add(new Task(inp_name, inp_description));
```

`Task` is abstract and can't be instantiated.

It can't find the variable `name` in `System.out.print(tasks.get(i).name);` and everywhere else `name` is used  , same goes for `completed` in `tasks.get(i).completed == false` and everywhere else `completed` is used.

Comment: I thought that too at first but the `if` statement doesn't necessarily need brackets so that piece would still compile. Your correction now has one too many brackets.

Comment: right, that if statement doesn't have an opening brace.

Comment: It's not missing its close brace. They're just deceptively aligned.

Comment: since all of the other if statements have opening braces, he needs 2 there.

Comment: @BinaryJudy i mean if you look at the entire program, all other if statements in the other methods have opening and closing braces.

Comment: @WonderWorld - they do, but why do you think that's an issue?

Comment: @WonderWorld Just cause all the others do doesn't mean that one has to :P

Comment: if you code you must be going one way or another in my opinion. use braces or not, don't do half your program with braces and the other half not. be concequent. I don't think it's an issue, i know its not an issue.

Comment: @WonderWorld - agreed, but it doesn't stop it from compiling.

Comment: @WonderWorld I agree, be consistent, aesthetics blah blah but the `view` method is fine the way it was, I mean it's not the root of the problem. Any way getting ot here.

Comment: @FluffmeisterGeneral thats true. My mistake, i saw the other if statements with opening braces, missed the one at that method and didnt check if it had an opening brace,

Answer (score 0):

You have not close brace on line 82 I guess

Answer (score 0):

So, it was a mixture of a lot of things.

*changing new to newTask

*adding the open brace at the if statement in view